# Marketing Cloud Connector with Sales Cloud is not updating Email on Subscriber Records

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

We have a series of import definitions in Marketing Cloud that creates Salesforce Data Extensions from Reports in Sales Cloud. One of the Contacts in Sales Cloud has an updated email address, but that updated email is not reflected in MC in the Subscriber record and is still sending emails to the old email. Isn't the point of the MC Connector to keep the contact data synched including the Contact ID and Email in the subscriber record in MC?

Answer (score 0):

All subscribers list is not, as you have already realised, being updated by the Marketing Cloud Connector. In order to keep your email addresses accurate in All Subscribers, you will meed to create an automation which:

1. queries the Lead/Contacts synchronised data extensions
2. compares the email addresses there, with email addresses in All Subscribers
3. identifies the Subscriber Keys for which the email addresses differ
4. updates the email address to the new one in All Subscribers

I have described the process of [updating email address in all subscribers here.](https://digitalmarketingoncloud.com/salesforce-marketing-cloud/updating-email-address-in-all-subscribers/)

You could also use Journey Builder to send your emails. This will actually update the email address in All Subscribers during send.

Comment: thank you! do you happen to have sample SQL for that type of automation?

Comment: Did you read my article, @Shira? There is SQL which you can easily adapt to lookup your contacts and leads with different email address than in All Subscribers